# Backup Outlook data for several users in one go?

Tags: backup, outlook

Is there any backup software that can backup outlook/addressbook/contacts (outlook contacts) on Windows for all users in one go ?

Having to click-through all of it for every user on the PC manually is just too slow and too tiresome.

While I am at it, also restore PST automagically, if a user on the new PC has the same name ?

Answer (score 1):

ReliefJet Essentials Professional Edition provides the command line you can use to run on all computers or run by schedule. It contains many tools you can use for backup purposes. For example, [Backup Outlook and Exchange Folders](https://www.reliefjet.com/Essentials/Features/OutlookFolderBackup).